# How to tell if there was a save or validation attempt in a Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

I need to check if a model has had any attempt to be saved or validated without actually saving/validating it. The method `#valid?` does run the validations, so it doesn't fit here.

Comment: I highly doubt that you can or should do this. It's *your code*. You should know whether you've called `save` or `valid?`. If you're having to look for some internal validation state just to figure this out, you probably need to rethink how you're implementing your solution. If you tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve, we can probably tell you the correct solution, which won't involve asking a model whether anybody has called "save" on it.

Comment: I wasn't doing anything that really required that it was more about curiosity. I was looking for an elegant syntax to switch the display of errors messages or success message, but only after the model was validated/saved, since it would be in the same view that is used before the submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [add a custom validation method](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#performing-custom-validations). Your method will be executed on any validation attempt. You can set a flag inside your validation method to know if it has been executed. But I see no point in this task. I doubt you really should do this.

Comment: Actually I considered flagging it with a callback or something, but I thought Rails would already have something. I honestly think that `#valid?` shouldn't do anything besides telling if the validation ran or not - I think it's counter-intuitive.